# PDOException could not find driver

Tags: symfony

im working with symfony and when i type in console this:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

i have the next errors

> **[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]**
>
> An exception occured in driver: could not find driver

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
> could not find driver

> [PDOException]
> could not find driver

I've been following this  link in order to sort it out

[PDOException “could not find driver” in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308147/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-php)

this is what i get when i run `php -m`

```
root@asus-K53SD:/opt/lampp/htdocs/symfonycurso# php -m
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlr    eader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib
Zend Modules
Zend OPcache
```

i uncommented this and restart the server

extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll

this is my parameter.yml

> Added database_driver  : pdo_mysql and password removed (before was null)
>
> ```
>  # This file is auto-generated during the composer install
> parameters:
> database_driver  : pdo_mysql
> database_host: 127.0.0.1
> database_port:
> database_name: blog
> database_user: root
> database_password:
> mailer_transport: smtp
> mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
> mailer_user:
> mailer_password:
> secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
> ```

anyone know how can i fix this errors?? can be the problem that im working on PHP7

NOTE: Using lampp on linux

Comment: Your Symfony parameters.yml says you're using `pdo_mysql`, so there's no need to load `pdo_pgsql` (this is PostgreSQL)... load `pdo_mysql` in php.ini and you're set.

Comment: @ccKep I added the line    database_driver  : pdo_mysql   because i saw it in other post.
when you say " to load pdo_mysql in php.ini" you mean to add ...
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=pdo_mysql.dll

in the php.ini file ... i tried too. restarted lampp and delete var/cache (symfony)

in my phpinfo i can see

API Extensions  mysqli,pdo_mysql

Comment: `NOTE: Using lampp on linux`, why would you add `.dll` files to your extension list in php.ini on a linux device? Also: If `phpinfo()` actually says `PDO` and `pdo_mysql` are loaded, what's the new error message from symfony?

Comment: @ccKep im just following the steps of others post with similar problem. I have no experience dealing with extension in lampp. Nevertheless.. i would say that phpinfo() have always said that pdo_mysql is enable. The thing is that many post point out that the problem is... because a line has to be uncomment or added.... None of them worked out to me

Answer (score 7):

Using *LAMP* you don't need to enable php_pdo_mysql.dll in the .ini file.
Instead, run this below command in cli,

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql` (Use specific PHP version which you used).

Now you can see `pdo_mysql` module by running `php -m` command.

Then, you clear the cache in symfony and run the symfony commands.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php version and versions your modules for php. I had problem after php update from 7.0 to 7.1. PHP migrate should help you. For exmaple http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.php

Comment: I couldnt find the problem but i sorted out working with window 10.

Answer (score 0):

It generally happens when symfony does not find the driver to connect to mysql. for me i had no mysql driver installed so i did following in my terminal :

```
// I have php version 7.2 
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql to install the mysql
```

then i ran following in my terminal to create database

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

which worked perfectly. I hope this does help to some one having similar problem