# Doctrine database creating symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Im trying to create database in mySQL DB using command "php bin/console doctrine:database:create"
and i get this error:

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 128:

  An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver  


In Exception.php line 18:

  could not find driver  


In PDOConnection.php line 39:

  could not find driver
```

Here is my .env file

```
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
#
# DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
 DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/myDB"
# DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

Comment: MySQL extension isn't install, so PHP cannot find the database driver. Install it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDOException could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43530999/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: Please make sure that you have pdo_mysql driver on your system or docker image, also you have to install php-mysql extension

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to check for symfony requirement `symfony check:requirements`
2. Try to install php-mysql extension, don't forget to restart/reload your server service after intalling extension