# Cant connect to mysqli with PDO php

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

```
<?php
class DB {

    private static function connect() {
            $pdo = new PDO('mysqli:host=localhost;dbname=SocialNetwork;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $pdo;
    }

    public static function query($query, $params = array()) {
            $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute($params);

            if (explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT') {
            $data = $statement->fetchAll();
            return $data;
            }
    }

}
```

When i try to insert data in the db it gets this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\xampp\htdocs\social-media\classes\DB.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\social-media\classes\DB.php(5): PDO->__construct('mysqli:host=loc...', 'root', '') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\social-media\classes\DB.php(11): DB::connect() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\social-media\create-account.php(10): DB::query('SELECT username...', Array) #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\social-media\classes\DB.php on line 5

Comment: There's no `mysqli` __uri__ for PDO. It is `mysql`: `new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDOException “could not find driver” in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308147/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate `pdo_mysql` in your php.ini

Look for a row with `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` using `CTRL+F` and restart your web environment.

Answer (score 0):

The driver name is not correct. Use "mysql:..."

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=SocialNetwork;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
```