# Can't generate my database with Doctrine ORM (Could not find driver)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

So, I just started using Doctrine, and it's also my first time using Symfony 5.
I used the Maker bundle to generate my first entity, and I completed the DATABASE_URL in my .env, but I can't generate my database with "php bin/console make:migration".

I got these errors:

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 106:
                                                          
  An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver  
                                                          

In PDOConnection.php line 31:
                         
  could not find driver  
                         

In PDOConnection.php line 27:
                         
  could not find driver
```

I searched for a solution, most of the time it's because the corresponding extension is missing... but not in my case !

This is my DATABASE_URL in my .env. I didn't modified anything else.

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://myusername:mypassword@localhost:3306/mydatabase?serverVersion=5.7
```

I'm a complete newbie, and I'm a bit lost.

Can you help me please ?

Thank you !

EDIT: sorry, I totally forgot the most important. Im on Windows 10 with the last version of WAMP, and I installed PHP 7.4.7.
All the extensions are activated, and php -m return them !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDOException “could not find driver” in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308147/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-php)

Comment: on which operating system is this? because it's definitely some package missing or the php config being incomplete. please check that `php -m` outputs `pdo_mysql`. if it doesn't (which is very very likely), install the os package for it: php-mysql (debian/ubuntu). that might already do it (assuming the correct os). if it still doesn't, check in `/etc/php/`, different ini files are used. normally php-mysql puts a file into conf.d for that extension, however, some systems don't (default debian might not, other linuxes don't, windows doesn't)

Comment: if your system doesn't have a pdo-mysql or pdo_mysql file in conf.d, you should modify php.ini, or something with cli and finde the line that starts with a `;` and has `extension=pdo_mysql` in it, and remove the `;` in front of it. that will enable the extension.

Comment: forgot to mention: php.ini is normally used. for web-servers php-fpm.ini or something might be used, some systems have a separate ini file for cli. edit the right ones (or all of those ^^). finally, you might have to restart php processes if you're running any (symfony webserver, if you're running a proper webserver, you might need to edit php-fpm stuff too)

Comment: @Atomzwieback It's a very old thread and I don't have any files mentionned in it.

Sorry, I forgot to mention the OS ! ! I'm on Windows 10 with the last version of WAMP and PHP 7.4.7 (but I think I'm gonna roll back to 7.4.0). I already have all the extensions installed.

So... Finally, I switched to PHP 7.4.0, it was not working. I shutdown my PC to go to sleep, and today... it works.
Windows seem to be so random compared to Linux when it comes to developpment...

Thank you all for your answers !