# How can I get a database running on Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, mysql-connector

**OBJECTIVE:**

I am trying to simply create a database using doctrine in Symfony.  I have my project installed in xampp>htdocs

**I HAVE TRIED:**

I have the apache server running and can view my site locally no problem.
When I follow the instructions in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#installing-doctrine), I am able to successfully run these two commands:

```
composer require symfony/orm-pack
composer require --dev symfony/maker-bundle
```

I then go to my **.env file** and change this line:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=5.7"
```

to be this line:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:pass@127.0.0.1:3306/symphart
```

-I have configured the root user to use the password "pass" and haved logged in to phpmyadmin -successfully.

-php.ini-production and php.ini-development both have pdo_mysql enabled

**THE PROBLEM:**

When I run the command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

I get the error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\symphart>php bin/console doctrine:database:create
[error] Error thrown while running command "doctrine:database:create". Message: "An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver"


In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 128:

  An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver


In Exception.php line 18:

  could not find driver


In PDOConnection.php line 37:

  could not find driver
```

Here is a screenshot of the error message:
[image: error message screenshot]

Comment: Run "php -m" and verify you have the mysqli extension installed and enabled.  If not then enable it in your php.ini file and try again.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.  Here are my modules:

[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib
[/PHP Modules]
When I take the semicolon away from in front of extension=mysqli and extension=pdo_mysql it has no effect.

Comment: Since you are using XAMPP, did you start MySQL from XAMPP Manager?

Comment: Yes. Both Apache and MySQL are running. I have stopped and restarted them several times just in case as well.  I am actually on the third re-install of Xampp and my third time through the tutorial as well.

Comment: "mbstring mysqlnd openssl" do you see mysql in there?  Fix that and you fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you Cerad. I am new.  How do I get mysql in there?  Please explain it like I am slow. Thank you. Lol

Comment: it appears you already have multiple php.ini files. the classic is to not know which one is currently used. apache usually uses a different one from command line. run `php --ini` to see which ini files are actually read on the command line. and change a relevant one to include the php module(s) required

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDOException “could not find driver” in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308147/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SOLUTION:

Windows 10 has two files in the Xampp folder with the ".ini" extension, and neither are what you need.  Uncommenting stuff in them did nothing for me. It wouldn't add modules.

On windows 10 you need to look in
"C:\Xampp\php" for a file called "configuration".  It's exactly like an ini file but has no extension.  Editing THAT file will enable modules.

Thanks for all the effort everyone put into answering my question. You were all essentially right.  Just missing the naming convention for Windows 10 it seems.

Answer (score 0):

First: The best practice is to use Symfony server. download Symfony from Symfony site.

Second: The right way is to have an outsider version of PHP not related to xammp or something else. and make sure you added the right path for PHP in system variables.

Download it from here:
https://www.php.net/downloads.php
Then enable the extensions in .ini file.

For being sure that you are using the right PHP version reinstall composer and select the right path for PHP during the install process.