# Symfony 5 / Doctrine : could not find driver

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, doctrine, driver

I am trying to create a MySQL database for a Symfony 5.1 application with Doctrine.

I am using PHP 7.4.11 with `extension=pdo_mysql` activated in `php.ini`. It is working fine in php info: Mysql 5.7.11.

In the `.env` file, I have:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/symerp?serverVersion=5.7
```

And in `doctrine.yaml`:

```
dbal:
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        charset: utf8mb4
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

Now, when I want to create my new database (symerp), I use the command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

And it fails, with error

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 110:  An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver

I found plenty of issues like this one in forums, and everytime the suggestions where "check your extention=pdo_mysql in your php.ini"... but in the end, the issue was not solved.

Has somebody else faced this issue and solved it?

Comment: You also need to have the mysql extension enabled.  Work your way through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64414143/how-can-i-get-a-database-running-on-symfony#comment113906608_64414143).

Comment: Did u restart your web server ?

Comment: Do you see a pdo_mysql in the output of phpinfo() ?

Comment: Is MySql server running? If you are using some version of a LAMP/MAMP stack, there is often a GUI control for this.