# Symfony can't generate entity

Tags: symfony, entity

I'm a newbie of symfony and I'm reading the book. At this page https://symfony.com/doc/6.2/the-fast-track/en/8-doctrine.html, I used `symfony console make:entity Conference` to make an entity called Conference, but I receive this error:

> In ExceptionConverter.php line 87:
>
> An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver
>
> In Exception.php line 28: could not find driver
>
> In Driver.php line 34: could not find driver

How i can i solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDOException “could not find driver” in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308147/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-php)

Comment: The error is quite clear. You are missing the driver on your server. Which database are you using?

Comment: Postgre, container in Docker Desktop